# Partial View Count=0, value not being sent to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Only the value of the Partial view form is not being passed to the controller.:/ FounderInvestmentVM is the one whose partial view i have created,this VM is inside of PropertyVM.The other values are passed to the controller but not that of Partial View. It always gives `FounderInvestments Count=0` when i put a debugger and see it :/

This is my PROPERTY VM containing FounderInvestorVM:-

```
namespace propertyMgmt.ViewModel.PropertyViewModel
{
    public class PropertyViewModel
    {     
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Property Title")]
        public string PropertyTitle { get; set; }
        ......
        public List<FounderInvestmentViewModel> FounderInvestments { get; set; }=new List<>(FounderInvestmentViewModel);
    }
}
```

This is FounderInvestorVM:-

```
public class FounderInvestmentViewModel
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }
        public int InvestorId { get; set; }
        public double Investment { get; set; }
        public int InstallmentPeriod { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FounderInvestorList { get; set; }
    }
```

This is My COntroller:-

```
public ActionResult Create(PropertyViewModel _propertyViewModel)
    {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        Property property = new Property();
        property.Id = _propertyViewModel.Id ?? 0;
        property.PropertyTitle = _propertyViewModel.PropertyTitle;
        ........other properties......        
        }
        _propertyQueryProcessor.Create(property);
        foreach(var investment in _propertyViewModel.FounderInvestments)
           {
               FounderInvestment _founderInvestment = new FounderInvestment
               {
                   Id = investment.Id??0,
                   InstallmentPeriod = investment.InstallmentPeriod,
                   InvestorId = investment.InvestorId,
                   PropertyId = investment.PropertyId,
                   Investment = investment.Investment
               };
               _founderInvestmentQueryProcessor.Create(_founderInvestment);    
    }
```

THIS IS THE PARTIAL VIEW:-

```
@model propertyMgmt.ViewModel.FounderInvestmentViewModel
@{
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "PropertyViewModel"; //bind to main model
}

<div class="founderInvestmentDetails">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("founderInvestmentDetails"))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id, new { @class = "id" })

        @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.PropertyId, new { @name = "PropertyId" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FounderInvestorList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.FounderInvestorList,Model.FounderInvestorList , "Select Investor", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FounderInvestorList, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.InvestorId, new { @name = "InvestorId" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Investment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Investment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",@type="number" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Investment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })              
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.InstallmentPeriod, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @type = "number" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.InstallmentPeriod, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InstallmentPeriod, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })                
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

And finally this is the main VIEW:-

```
@model propertyMgmt.ViewModel.PropertyViewModel.PropertyViewModel
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Property", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropertyTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PropertyTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    .....(other form groups)
    <div id="founderInvestmentDetails" class="form-group">
        @foreach(var founderInvestmentDetails in Model.FounderInvestments)
        {
        @Html.Partial("_FounderInvestmentDetails", founderInvestmentDetails)
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: 1. Remove the `ViewData.TemplateInfo...` line of code. 2. Its `BeginCollectionItem("FounderIvestments")` - to match the property name.

Comment: @StephenMuecke see the chat if you are free :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry,there was a silly mistake here.As @Stephen Muecke pointed out

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("founderInvestmentDetails"))
```

Should be

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("FounderInvestments"))
```

Because BeginCollectionItem uses name of the `Collection` it is working on.